# How to check if edge already exists?

Tags: java, jgrapht

I am using `JGraphT`. I was trying to check if the edge exists and for that I was using getAllEdges. As the specification says *"returns a set of all edges connecting source vertex to target vertex if such vertices exist in this graph. If any of the vertices does not exist or is null, returns null. If both vertices exist but no edges found, returns an empty set"* I understand that I have to create two conditions. So the first one

```
Graph.getAllEdges(vertex1,vertex2)==null
```

is fine. But what about second one? I was trying

```
Graph.getAllEdges(vertex1,vertex2).isEmpty()==true
Graph.getAllEdges(vertex1,vertex2).emptySet()==true
```

but none of them is working. So how should it be?

Comment: Dump their output to see what they return

Comment: What's wrong with `Graph.getAllEdges(vertex1,vertex2).isEmpty()`? Note that you do not need to compare an already boolean value to being `true` or `false`. Additionally, the [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface does not know a method `emptySet`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose  NetBeans says: cannot find method: getAllEdges(int, int); But it is not saying that while trying to do null.